# How to test conditional rendering provided a method that returns boolean?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, vite, ts-jest

I'm wanting to test a conditional rendering, but I'm having trouble getting the function (userHasAccess) from the custom hook and simulating a return of true, so that the element is rendered on screen.

**useData.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const useData = () => {

  function userHasAccess(access: 'student' | 'teacher' | 'admin'): boolean {
    return getLoggedUser()?.access === access
  }

  others functions...

  return {
    userHasAccess,
    others functions...
  }
}

export default useData;
```

**Sidebar.tsx**

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const { userHasAccess } = useData();

  return (
      <ul>
        {userHasAccess('admin') && <li><Link to='usuarios'>Users</Link></li>}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**Sidebar.test.tsx**

```
  it('should render correctly for admin', () => {
    render(<BrowserRouter><Sidebar /></BrowserRouter>)

    expect(screen.getByText("Users")).toBeInTheDocument();

  })
})
```

How can I test in this situation so that:

expect(screen.getByText("Users")).toBeInTheDocument();

Pass the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you just to need mock `userHasAccess` to return `true` value

Try the code below:

```
// Sidebar.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'; 
import useData from './useData';

jest.mock('./useData');

describe('Sidebar', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should render correctly for admin', () => {
    useData.mockReturnValue({ userHasAccess: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true) });

    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Sidebar />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText('Users')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: You are a master, it worked buddy. I'm having trouble creating a mock custom hook.

Comment: I noticed that when mock is defined in module or describe scope, it affects all tests. Is that normal?

Comment: @gab define `afterAll` except `afterEach` and tell me if it works for you. :). It shouldn't affect other tests from non test file if you clear mocks after test execution. I wonder how that can affect you,, if you defined `afterEach`..

Comment: If mock is still affecting other tests, you can move this test to separate file. If you still have an issue with mock, describe your structure, I'll try to help.

Comment: @gab can you split tests to separate test specs?

Comment: actually `mock` is executed globally for current test spec. You can split your tests among separate spec files. Like admin.spec.ts , teacher.spec.ts, etc.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/tests/selector/getClassSelector.spec.ts  - here I mock my function in separate spec file. And mock is executed per spec, other spec files wouldn't receive this function being mocked

Comment: I solved it by adding `useData.mockReturnValue({ userHasAccess: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false) });` in the teacher's if, and there was no error :D

Comment: Yep, sure, this also would work :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I started studying Tests today, so I'm a little lost, the official documentation doesn't help much :S.

Separating the tests seems like good practice.